# Can the usage of a Semaphore in async methods lead to deadlocks on WPF dispatcher thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, httpclient, semaphore

I am deriving from `System.Net.HttpClient` class to implement a client that handles token retrieval and refreshal. The client is initialized using all the required authentication parameters and might potentially be used concurrently. In that case I need to prevent the client from requesting multiple tokens (for different requests).

I am not sure whether my code might lead to deadlocks in a WPF application if the user launches multiple web requests on the dispatcher thread (because the semaphore is non-reentrant, so the dispatcher thread *might* be blocked while waiting on the semaphore, and the original task might not be able to complete if the dispatcher thread is blocked).

```
public class ApiClient : HttpClient
{
    public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_token == null)
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
            try
            {
                if (_token == null)
                {
                    // _token = await _tokenService.AcquireToken(xx,xx,xx);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
        else if (_token.IsExpired)
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
            try
            {
                if (_token.IsExpired)
                {
                    // _token = await _tokenService.RefreshToken(xx,xx,xx);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Deadlock occurs when there are 2 threads waiting for each other. So basically if your Dispatcher Thread wait for Api Thread(that is actually happening) and Api Thread wait for a response from Dispatcher Thread(that's should not be the case) then you will get a deadlock. I don't see why a deadlock should occur in your scenario. The worst case would be a timeout if there are too many requests and some will not manage to finish in time.

Comment: But I would definitely get a deadlock when using the synchronous Wait() method of the semaphore, is that right?

Comment: I don't think so. If you will use Wait() instead of WaitAsync() the situation about deadlocks should not change unless Api Thread in some hidden way would try to access Dispatcher Thread. The difference would be more inefficient thread usage: ApplicationPool Task would not return to the Pool if semaphore is full, but will be blocked waiting. So when the next request will arive the blocked thread would not be able to serve the request and new thread would be created. So you will end up with much more threads.

Comment: Btw, I would recommend reading [Threading in C#, by Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Deadlocks) about multithreading, it made a lot of things clearer to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the dispatcher thread might be blocked while waiting on the semaphore

This can't happen with the code you've shown. It's using *asynchronous* waits (`await`), so the thread won't be blocked.